# Found a buried ~2 in ABS pipe near my foundation, what could it be used for?

Tags: landscaping

I was digging a hole to plant a new tree near my home and while digging I found a 2 inches (or 1 1/2 - I didn't measure it) ABS pipe (the same you use for a sink drain in a bathroom) buried about 2-3 inches deep and about 1 foot away from the foundation. I don't know where it comes from or where it goes. It's on the side of the house, between my house and the neighbor house.

I was wondering what could it be.

Some more infos:

- House was built in 1970, but I don't know when this pipe was installed (bought the house last year)
- Region is Québec, Canada
- House has a basement so the floor of my basement is about 7 or 8 feet below that pipe

Comment: Untill you establish its ends points it may well be a buried bit of pipe doing nothing useful except confusing you...

Comment: It could be part of a sprinkler system. If it's only 2 - 3 inches deep, find the ends.

Comment: Could be a homemade electrical conduit. Do you have a garage or outbuilding that it might be going to?

Comment: Only other building is a shed, but there's no electricity in it. At first, I thought it could be a pipe to empty a pool, but I looked back till 2007 on Google Maps and there's no pool. Maybe it was before. Don't think it's a sprinkler system either. Could be some sort of drain system for the land to drain faster. I guess I'll have to find where it goes and where it comes from to be sure.